# Global override of mouse cursor with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

In my web application I try to implement some drag and drop functionality. I have a global JavaScript component which does the the basic stuff. This object is also responsible for changing the mouse cursor, depending of the current drag operation (move, copy, link). On my web page there are various HTML elements which define an own cursor style, either inline or via a CSS file.

So, is there a way for my central drag and drop component to change the mouse cursor globally, independent from the style of the element the mouse cursor is over?

I tried:

```
document.body.style.cursor = "move"
```

and

```
document.body.style.cursor = "move !important"
```

But it doesn't work. Every time I drag over an element which defines a cursor style, the cursor changes to that style.

Sure, I could change the style of the element I'm currently dragging over, but then I have to reset it when I leave the element. This seems a little bit to complicated. I'm looking for a global solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Important Update (2021):**

The MDN page for [element.setCapture()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture) clearly indicates that this feature is deprecated and non-standard, and should not be used in production.

The  browser support table at the bottom of that page indicates that it's only supported in Firefox and IE.

Original answer below

---

***Please: don't massacre your CSS!***

To implement a drag and drop functionality, you have to use a very important API: **element.setCapture()**, which does the following :

- All mouse events are redirected to the target element of the capture, regardless of where they occured (even outside the browser window)
- The cursor will be the cursor of the target element of the capture, regardless where the mouse pointer is.

You have to call **element.releaseCapture()** or **document.releaseCapture()** to switch back to normal mode at the end of the operation.

***Beware of a naïve implementation of drag and drop:*** you can have a lot of painful issues, like for example (among others): what happens if the mouse is released outside the browser's window, or over an element which has a handler that stops propagation. Using setCapture() solves all this issues, and the cursor style as well.

You can read [this excellent tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setCapture) that explains this in detail if you want to implement the drag and drop yourself.

Maybe you could also use [jQuery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) if possible in your context.

Comment: setCapture works in IE and FF/Moz, but appears Chrome doesn't support this awesome feature :(

Comment: setCapture only works in Firefox today (not in IE 11). But it can be used when it's there.

Comment: 2021 (the other side after 2020), Mozilla docs illustrates https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setCapture:
"This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future".

Answer (score 9):

I tried using `setPointerCapture` which worked great. The downside is, that (of cause) all pointer events will not work as before. So I lost hover styles etc.

My solution now is pretty straight forward and for my usecase better suited then the above CSS solutions.

To set the cursor, I add a new stylesheet to head:

```js
const cursorStyle = document.createElement('style');
cursorStyle.innerHTML = '*{cursor: grabbing!important;}';
cursorStyle.id = 'cursor-style';
document.head.appendChild(cursorStyle);
```

To reset it, I simply remove the stylesheet:

```js
document.getElementById('cursor-style').remove();
```

Comment: This one works well with my react use case—I made a custom hook that's essentially: `const useTempCursor = (enabled: boolean) => { useEffect(() => { if (enabled) { /* add <style> element */ } return () => { /* remove <style> element */ }; }, [enabled]);};`

Answer (score 7):

```
document.body.style.cursor = "move"
```

should work just fine.

However, I recommend to do the global styling via CSS.

define the following:

```
body{
   cursor:move;
}
```

The problem is, that the defined cursors on the other elements override the body style.

You could do someting like this:

```
your-element.style.cursor = "inherit"; // (or "default")
```

to reset it to the inherited style from the body or with CSS:

```
body *{
   cursor:inherit;
}
```

Note however, that `*` is normally considered a bad selector-choice.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `element.setCapture()` does not work for IE

I use a brute force approach - open a transparent div on top of entire page for the duration of drag-drop.

```
.tbFiller {
   position:absolute;
   z-index:5000; 
   left:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%; 
   background-color:transparent;
   cursor:move;
}

...

function dragStart(event) {
    // other code...
    document.tbFiller=document.createElement("div");
    document.tbFiller.className="tbFiller"
}

function dragStop(event) {
    // other code...
    document.tbFiller.parentNode.removeChild(document.tbFiller);
}
```

Comment: setCapture works in IE, but don't think Chrome has anything like it

Comment: setCapture is not working in IE 11. Firefox says it's a Microsoft API, they may have dropped it again. But you don't need an overlay div, a CSS rule and setting a class is enough.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't seem to override the 'noentry' drag-and-drop cursor, which is what I wanted

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to some of the other answers here for clues, this works well:

```css
/* Disables all cursor overrides when body has this class. */
body.inheritCursors * {
    cursor: inherit !important;
}
```

Note: I **didn't** need to use `<html>` and `document.documentElement`; instead, `<body>` and `document.body` work just fine:

```js
document.body.classList.add('inheritCursors');
```

This causes [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) elements of `<body>` (since it now has this `inheritCursors` class) to inherit their cursor from `<body>` itself, which is whatever you set it to:

```js
document.body.style.cursor = 'progress';
```

Then to yield back control to the descendant elements, simply remove the class:

```js
document.body.classList.remove('inheritCursors');
```

and to [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) the cursor on the `<body>` to the default do:

```js
document.body.style.cursor = 'unset';
```

Comment: ⚠️ Note: This (expectedly) fails in the case of a custom element with a shadow tree if the shadow tree contains a child with a cursor rule.

Comment: This approach in general does work, however due to a massive style update on the page (with `body *` selector), the cursor change is lagging behind the necessity to change it. Which feels like a laggy UX.

Comment: @KostiantynKo Good luck finding a good alternative besides knowing exactly where all over the codebase the cursor is changing. Hacky environments require hacky solutions.

Comment: Well, I just found out that in browsers other than Chromium-based, the performance of this solution is just straight unbearable (Firefox and mobile browsers). I have a few alternatives on my mind though, those must be faster

Comment: @KostiantynKo Your comments are not very useful if no alternatives are provided/mentioned. Unless you are doing what I said, though, I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do and it works in Firefox, Chrome, Edge and IE as of 2017.

Add this CSS rule to your page:

```
html.reset-all-cursors *
{
    cursor: inherit !important;
}
```

When the `<html>` element has the "reset-all-cursors" class, this overrides all cursors that are set for elements individually in their `style` attribute – without actually manipulating the elements themselves. No need to clean up all over the place.

Then when you want to override your cursor on the entire page with that of any `element`, e. g. the element being dragged, do this in JavaScript:

```
element.setCapture && element.setCapture();
$("html").addClass("reset-all-cursors");
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("cursor", $(element).css("cursor"), "important");
```

It uses the `setCapture` function where it is available. This is currently just Firefox although they say it's a Microsoft API. Then the special class is added to the entire document, which disables all custom cursors. Finally set the cursor you want on the document so it should appear everywhere.

In combination with capturing events, this may even extend the dragging cursor to outside of the page and the browser window. `setCapture` does this reliably in Firefox. But elsewhere it doesn't work every time, depending on the browser, its UI layout, and the path along which the mouse cursor leaves the window. ;-)

When you're finished, clean up:

```
element.releaseCapture && element.releaseCapture();
$("html").removeClass("reset-all-cursors");
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("cursor", "");
```

This includes jQuery for `addClass` and `removeClass`. In simple scenarios you could just plain compare and set the `class` attribute of `document.documentElement`. This will break other libraries like Modernizr though. You can get rid of the `css` function if you know the element's desired cursor already, or try something like `element.style.cursor`.

Comment: This isn't great, because changing the reset-all-cursors class will cause every element on the page to reevaluate its style, which is slow and causes any animations, etc. on the page to hitch.

Comment: I haven't observed any issues with it until now. And I don't understand "animations hitch". At least in my case no animations behave anyhow noticeably.

Comment: For those not using jQuery: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement

Answer (score 0):

A performance-acceptable, but not ideal either, solution that I ended up using, is actually to change the `cursor` prop of element directly under the pointer, and then return it back to original when pointer moved to another element. It works comparatively fast, as just a few elements change their style while moving pointer around, but visually you might sometimes see a short glimpse of "original" cursor. I consider it a much more acceptable tradeoff.

So, the solution, in TypeScript:

```
let prevElement: HTMLElement | undefined;
let prevElementOriginalCursor: string | undefined;

export const setTemporaryCursor = (element: HTMLElement, cursor: string | undefined) => {
  // First, process the incoming element ASAP
  let elementOriginalCursor: string | undefined;
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    if (element && prevElement !== element) {
      elementOriginalCursor = element.style.cursor;
      element.style.cursor = cursor ?? '';
    }
  });

  // Then process the previous element, not so critical
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    if (prevElement && prevElement !== element) {
      prevElement.style.cursor = prevElementOriginalCursor ?? '';
      prevElementOriginalCursor = elementOriginalCursor;
    }
    prevElement = element;
  });
};

export const resetTemporaryCursor = () => {
  if (prevElement) {
    prevElement.style.cursor = prevElementOriginalCursor ?? '';
    prevElementOriginalCursor = undefined;
    prevElement = undefined;
  }
};
```

just call `setTemporaryCursor` while user moves mouse, and call `resetTemporaryCursor()` when drag process is wrapped up (on `MouseUp` for instance).

This does the job for me. The use of `requestAnimationFrame` is optional, and probably could be improved with experimentation.